# VDSM hook VMFEX custom parameters do not work

Tags: redhat, kvm

On RHEV 3.2 hypervisor with RHEL 6.4 has been installed vdsm hook for vmfex configuration during virtual machine startup.
RPM package - *vdsm-hook-vmfex-4.12.1-2.el6.noarch*
Custom properties are configured via GUI as follow:

```
'00:1a:4a:09:09:12':'DB'
```

where fist parameter is MAC address and second is profile name in UCS.
Virtual machine doesn't start due to problem with VDSM hook.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it out.
The custom properties should be wrapped with curly braces as follow:
{'00:1a:4a:09:09:12':'DB'}
to make this work.